# multiple map with rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am trying to create sections for a tableview from an array of item on which each array item is a sections item.

> My quesiton is how can I make `cart.map` return an array of
>   CartProductSection ([CartProductSection]) instead of assign it to a variable. Thanks.

My code
    let cart: BehaviorRelay
 struct Output {
        let items: Observable<[CartProductSection]>
    }

```
           var sectionPerSupplierItems: [CartProductSection] = []

            _ = cart.map { (cart)  in 
                let cartItemsPerSupplier = self.sortModelItemPerSection(items: cart.items)

                print(cart.items.count)
                 _ = cartItemsPerSupplier.map {  (cartItemsPerSupplier) in

                    var items: [CartProductSectionItem] = []
                    for cartItem in cartItemsPerSupplier.cartItems {
                         items.append(CartProductSectionItem.cartItem(viewModel: CartItemViewModel(with: cartItem)))
                    }

                    sectionPerSupplierItems.append(CartProductSection.cartItemModel
(title: cartItemsPerSupplier.companyName, items: items))
                }
            }

            return Output(items: Observable.just(sectionPerSupplierItems))
```

Comment: There's not enough context to go on. What is the type of `cart`? Are you using `RxDataSources`? What type are you expecting to feed into the table view?

Comment: code updated, yes am using rxdatasrouce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would likely write the code like this (I'm still making a bunch of assumptions here.):

```
let items = cart
    .map { [unowned self] in self.sortModelItemPerSection(items: $0.items) }
    .map { cartItemsPerSuppliers in
        cartItemsPerSuppliers.map { CartProductSection.cartItemModel(from: $0) }
    }
return Output(items: items)
```

The above assumes something like this exists:

```
extension CartProductSection {
    static func cartItemModel(from supplier: CartItemsPerSupplier) -> CartProductSection {
        return cartItemModel(title: supplier.companyName, items: supplier.cartItems.map { CartProductSectionItem.cartItem(viewModel: CartItemViewModel(with: $0)) })
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if I were writing this, I would move `sortModelItemPerSection(items:)` out of the class so I didn't have to reference `self`.

Comment: Thank you! I got to learn new stuff from this :). Happy new year!